# Change Data Sources on ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, datasource, dataview

**Issue:** I have 2 datasources declared on my .aspx file as shown below:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="UsuarioDelete" SelectMethod="SelectMyAllNotME_Data" TypeName="BLLayer.Usuarios" OnInserted="ObjectDataSource_Inserted">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ConfirmDialogBox1" Name="id_usuario" PropertyName="Aceptar_CommandName" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="id_usuario" SessionField="id_usuario" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="id_pais" SessionField="id_pais" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" DeleteMethod="UsuarioDelete" SelectMethod="SelectMyAllNotME_Data" TypeName="BLLayer.Usuarios" OnInserted="ObjectDataSource_Inserted">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ConfirmDialogBox1" Name="id_usuario" PropertyName="Aceptar_CommandName" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="id_emp" QueryStringField="id_emp" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The method "SelectMyAllNotME_Data" is an overloaded method that in one he receives 2 values and in the other just one value, it is used to filter the information.
What I want to do is than in my onLoadPage method is something like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["id_emp"] != null)
    {
        GridViewUsers.DataSource = ObjectDataSource2.SelectMethod;
        GridViewUsers.DataMember = ObjectDataSource2.SelectMethod;
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewUsers.DataSource = ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod;
        GridViewUsers.DataMember = ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod;
    }
}
```

I've already tried this, but it isn't working, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the datasource in aspx just do

```
EnablePaging="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
GridViewUsers.DataBind();
```

Comment: Already made it, but it shows me this error: _Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The data source does not support server-side data paging._